# Client validation in OAuth 2.0 Authorization Grant Flow without client secret in Mobile apps

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4, pkce

While implementing OAuth 2.0 for mobile applications using Authorization Code grant type, we can generate a clientid on Identity provider while registering the application.(we are not generating client secret for mobile application)

My question is, how Identity server verifies that the first request of response_type=code&client_id=client_id  is coming from correct mobile application or not? As client id is in URL, so anyone can use read it and sends the request to authorization server.

**Update:**
according to https://auth0.com/docs/flows/concepts/auth-code-pkce, PKCE is introduce because client secret is not secure on mobile. and malicious applications can capture the custom url.

Now, as a hacker i can get the client ID of the application by monitoring mobile default browser using development window traffic of an app say A which is register with authentication server(IS). i got he client ID of stackoverflow which i am not disclosing it here. i will create a mobile malicious mobile application which will register custom url of actual mobile app A. this app will redirect with same clientid and redirect url and with PKCE challenge. Now, how IS will be able to identify whether request id coming from correct client or not. Since, as mentioned in link, if i am able to register malicious application to capture custom redirect url request of mobile, then i will be able to capture authentication code and perform rest of the workflow using malicious application.

Google takes the bundle identifier(IOS) or application signing(Android) while creating application. does it help somehow identifying application??

Answer (score 0):

Oauth2 requires SSL, so not everyone can read your url parameters. Url is also encrypted in SSL request. Your client asks DNS server for ip address. It sends request url without parameters to DNS. After obtaining ip address encrypted request is sent to that ip address.

Public clients are less safe than private clients, there is no doubt about that.

Answer on Edit part:
PKCE gives additional protection. First you have to generate some random value and calculate hash of that random value. In first request you send calculated hash and get code. In second request you send code and random value. This way if advesary steals your code he cannot get token because he needs your random value. Only you can know random value used to create hash, because if advesary knows your hash he cannot calculate random value from hash.  When you send token request to IS, IS calculates hash of your random value and compares it to the hash you sent in the code request. If they do match it is proof that you are the same guy who asked for code.

Comment: i am not sure about mobile device debugging, but cann't we tract request response using adb drive or something else in mobile browser just like we can track in chrome developer window. If yes, from there i can easily extract client id from url.

Comment: Such tools use man in the middle technique. If adversary does that while you are surfing you will get "Not secure" message in your browser.

Comment: i have seen in SPA(single page application), without any server, as well using only client id. we can view those spa traffic in our chrome development window without MIMA.

Comment: Chrome encrypts your request before sending it to Authorization server. Chrome can show request before encryption in development window. If adversary intercepts your message he cannot read it because it is encrypted with server public key and one needs to have Authorization server private key to decrypt the message.

Comment: i have an update on question. Please see if you can clarify on the same

Comment: i understand PKCE, but what i am not able to understand that how identity provider identifies that correct client is making first request(code) or not?  As only client identifier is client id and i can have client id as commented in question itself.

Comment: It doesn't. It just shows login page and user has to enter credentials.